# clang-tidy not applying naming

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy on Windows from MSVC (Clang 13.0.1 for MSVC 2022 amd). The renaming is applied to the header file, but not fully to the cpp file.

.clang-tidy

```
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase,           value: lower_case  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberCase,     value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMethodCase,     value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionCase,        value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ParameterCase,       value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase,        value: lower_case }
```

Header:

```
#pragma once
class NeedsTidying
{
  public:
    int addFunc(int argOne, int argTwo);
    int subFunc(int argOne, int argTwo) {
        return argOne - argTwo;
    }
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "tidy.hpp"
int NeedsTidying::addFunc(int argOne, int argTwo) {
    return argOne + argTwo;
}
```

clang-tidy arguments: clang-tidy --fix-errors -p build\compile_commands.json path_to_code*

clang-tidy gets applied to the header file as I expect, but the cpp file doesn't apply the class name or method renames as I expect:

```
int NeedsTidying::addFunc(int arg_one, int arg_two) {
    return arg_one + arg_two;
}
```

Comment: Run the command several times.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with clang-tidy-12 on linux. @273K Running the command several times is not an option since the first time you run it, it generates broken code that won't compile, which clang-tidy then complains about the second time around.